# Count How Many Columns in Dataframe before NaN

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan

I want to count how many column data (`pd.Dataframe`) before Nan data. My data:

```
df 
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13
Id                                                      
 A  1   1   2   3   3   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 B  6   6   7   7   8   9   10  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 C  1   2   3   3   4   5   6   6   7   7   8   9   10  NaN
```

my desire output:

```
df_result

    count       
Id                                                      
 A  5   
 B  7   
 C  13
```

thank you in advance for the answer.

Comment: forgive me I am a newbie in python and pandas, I tried many ways but can't found the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4    5     6    7    8    9   10   11    12    13
A  1  1  2  3  3  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  54.0
B  6  6  7  7  8  9.0  10.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   5.0   NaN
C  1  2  3  3  4  5.0   6.0  6.0  7.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  10.0   NaN

df = df.isnull().cumsum(axis=1).eq(0).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
A     5
B     7
C    13
dtype: int64
```

**Detail**:

First check `NaN`s:

```
print (df.isnull())
       0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9  \
A  False  False  False  False  False   True   True   True   True   True   
B  False  False  False  False  False  False  False   True   True   True   
C  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False   

      10     11     12     13  
A   True   True   True  False  
B   True   True  False   True  
C  False  False  False   True
```

Get [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) - `True`s are processes like `1`, `False` like `0`

```
print (df.isnull().cumsum(axis=1))
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13
A  0  0  0  0  0  1  2  3  4  5   6   7   8   8
B  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  2  3   4   5   5   6
C  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   1
```

Compare by `0`:

```
print (df.isnull().cumsum(axis=1).eq(0))
      0     1     2     3     4      5      6      7      8      9     10  \
A  True  True  True  True  True  False  False  False  False  False  False   
B  True  True  True  True  True   True   True  False  False  False  False   
C  True  True  True  True  True   True   True   True   True   True   True   

      11     12     13  
A  False  False  False  
B  False  False  False  
C   True   True  False
```

`Sum` boolean mask - `True`s like `1`s:

```
print (df.isnull().cumsum(axis=1).eq(0).sum(axis=1))
A     5
B     7
C    13
dtype: int64
```

Comment: good answer. May I ask what would be the difference between `cumsum` and `sum` in this case?

Comment: `sum` here is used for count `True`s, `cumsum` is used for remove values after first `NaN`s - it return cumulative sum - DataFrame, `sum` return `Series`

Comment: It's working for me. Thank you so much for detail explanation and example for a newbie like me.